# spice: unknown parameter ($)

Tags: ltspice, spice

This spice file

```
.include ntyp.md
.include ptyp.md

vvdd VDD GND_ 5
vgnd GND_ 0 0

vin IN GND_ pwl(0 0 100n 0 101n 5 200n 5 201n 0 300n 0 301n 5 400n 5)
.tran 1p 400n
.print tran v(IN) v(OUT)

M1 OUT IN GND_ GND_ EN l=5e-07 w=1.2e-06  $ (44 7.4 44.5 8.6)
M2 OUT IN VDD VDD EP l=5e-07 w=2.4e-06  $ (44 12.1 44.5 14.5)
```

gives the error `unknown parameter ($)` when I run it locally. I've tried this on AIM-spice and LTspice. However, when another person runs the same code on another computer it doesn't give this error. ntyp.md & ptype.md are located in the same folder as the spice file. I also tried an absolute path to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not all spice dialects are created equally

Comment: This spice was automatically generated by means of a L-edit extract. How would I know the "dialect" I extracted it to and how to run it?

Comment: read the documentation of whatever software you used to create it.

Comment: L-edit documentation seems to be non-existing.

Comment: In the `M1` and `M2` lines (last two) you have that sign. If it's meant to be a comment or some sort, then LTspice only accepts `;` or `*` (I think also `#`, not sure now). Solution: simply replace the offending character. Else, if they're meant to be parameters, then they're missing their designator (i.e. `Vto=1.5`, instead of simply `1.5`), otherwise I have no idea what they're meant to represent.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It's automatically generated so I'm not sure, but this is supposed to be an invertor.

Comment: @RungeKutta   try removing '$' as space separation should work

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes, I did read your comment. I'm not sure I'm following you. Replace it with what exactly? I know it's not supposed to be a comment or a line break. So, I thought this is what you meant.

Comment: @johnger I already tried this, results are in the question.

Comment: @johnger That is *not* the solution, as the following after the `$` is not a valid SPICE syntax.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen That was definitely not my intention. Sorry if I came across that way. I'm currently in the process of trying it.

Comment: It works in the sense that I get no more errors in AIM-spice but the plot remains [empty](https://i.imgur.com/JzQbWUr.png).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78091/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-runge-kutta).

Comment: I removed the irrelevant portions from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LTspice, `$` has a special significance which is not related to comments. The only availabel characters for comments are `;` and `*` (it seems also `#`). The rest following the `$` char in your code is not a valid SPICE syntax, so you could try to replace `$` with one of the aforementioned allowed characters, to comment the rest.

One other thing: `.plot` in LTspice doesn't do what you want, so if you want traces to be automatically plotted, one way to do it is to run the simulation (no need to fully run it, in case it takes hours or so), plot the desired waveforms, then activate the waveform viewer by L-Click on it and then either choose `File > Save`, or click on the `Save` icon on the toolbar. This will create an additional `.plt` file, holding the plot settings. From now on, whenever you *first* simulate the schematic, or when you open up the waveform viewer, the saved traces will be displayed.